# media query is triggering regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using *Bootstrap 4.0* and am creating a wordpress theme with it, I have placed the bootstrap.css file in the css folder of my theme and the bootstrap.js file in the js folder of my theme. These are the only files in those folders.

My code in the index.php folder is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php  bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">


</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

</body>


</html>
```

I'm expecting it to give a Navbar [like the one here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)

But instead, it collapses the Navbar as if it's on mobile. It  moves the "Navbar"  word all the way to the right and combines all the pages into a drop down which it moves to the left hand side of the screen.

I created an html file and it does the exact same thing.

My browser is set to 100%. I have never had this issue with Bootstrap.

Would anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this? I'm sure it's something extremely simply that I am simply missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navbar-toggleable-md` is not valid syntax in Bootstrap v4 (Beta).  The class name you're looking for to add responsive toggling of your hamburger menu is `navbar-expand-md`

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

The above link outlines version 4s Navbar component, including the toggle class.  This class was not used in version 3, but for information pertaining to the 3 to 4 transition I would encourage you to read their Migration documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: Hey can you link to your source for this? I'm building a site in bootstrap now and I want to be aware of all the changes between 3 -> 4 and alpha and beta